# Logic bricks disappeared in the Blender editor, but still work, can't find them

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I'm pretty new to Blender, but I have a model in which I defined a bunch of Sensors, Controllers, and Actuators that move my model in response to the keyboard in the blender game engine.

When I press [P]lay, the keyboard sensors I defined all work just fine. But when I look in the logic editor it doesn't show any sensors controllers or actuators. I don't know what changed between the last time I looked at the model and now.

> Is there any way I can somehow hide my definitions of sensors,
>   controllers, and actuators in some other layer or somewhere that I
>   perhaps don't know about?

---

This is what I see, but a half dozen logic bricks still function as expected.

[image]

Comment: _I have a model in which I defined a bunch of Sensors, Controllers, and Actuators_... In the image i see that the selected object is a Camera, select your model. As you are new i assume that you dont know that each object have independent logic sensors, etc. that can be linked to controllers of other objects

Comment: Oh duh! I absolutely did *not* know that. Thank you, I thought I was going crazy. :)  Please do post that as an answer, that's exactly what I needed to understand. @Strapicarus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I have a model in which I defined a bunch of Sensors, Controllers, and Actuators*... In the image i see that the selected object is a Camera, select your model. As you are new i assume that you *did not* know that each object have independent logic sensors, etc. [that can be linked to controllers of other objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91040/blender-game-engine-logics-sensors-and-python-script/91067#91067).

[Blender Manual: Game engine](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/game_engine/index.html)