# Trigger an event of a different object on object collision BGE

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I created a ghost box with a collision sensor. I have a bunch of 'coins' that will move from their hidden location to their desired location with their actuators.

I would like to somehow connect the box's collision sensor to activate all the coin's actuators, to move them to their new location with the motion actuator.

Is something like this possible with BGE? How would I connect these two?

Comment: Related: [blender game engine logics sensors and python script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91040/blender-game-engine-logics-sensors-and-python-script/91067#91067)

Comment: That helped. Selecting all your objects and connecting them from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can simply plug a senor from one object into an actuator on another, I find it cleaner to use messages.

Have object one (the ghost) trigger a message. Then on object two (the coin) have a message sensor trigger the motion.

Her are the logic bricks for the sensor object. It is just a collision sensor and a message actuator.
[image: message actuator triggered from a collision sensor]

Then on the coin object add a message sensor, to trigger whatever you need.
[image: logic bricks]

Note the subject in both message logic bricks has to be the same.

---

Now if you just want to go the quick and easy way (yet very messy) then just select both the sensor object and the coin and hook up the logic bricks cross object in the logic editor.
[image]